Why are the Hodge filtrations on cohomology canonically bounded?
If $X$ is a complex projective variety of dimension $n$ then the de Rham cohomology $H^{k}(X,\mathbb Q)$ naturally has a mixed Hodge structure with an increasing weight filtration $W_\bullet$ and a decreasing Hodge filtration $F^\bullet,$ where $W_{-1}=0$ and $W_{k}=H^k(X,\mathbb Q).$ My understanding is that Deligne constructed this MHS by defining $W_\bullet$ and $F^\bullet$ in terms of explicit differential forms coming from a resolution of $X.$ A consequence is that
\begin{align}\tag{1}
\mathrm{gr}_F^p\mathrm{gr}^W_mH^k(X,\mathbb C)=0
\end{align}
for $p\neq 0,\ldots, m$ simply because there are no $(p,q)$-forms for $pq<0.$
On the other hand, from the point of view of Saito's theory of mixed Hodge modules, $H^k(X,\mathbb Q)$ inherits a natural mixed Hodge structure as the cohomology of the constant MHM $\mathbb Q_X^H[n].$ $$\mathbb H^{-n+k}(X,\mathbb Q_X^H[n])\cong H^k(X,\mathbb C)$$ It turns out that the Hodge structures defined by Deligne and Saito are the same, and the isomorphism above is one of MHSs.
Question: Is it possible to see that $(1)$ holds for $p\neq 0,\ldots, m$ purely from the theory of mixed Hodge modules, without appealing to the fact that this Hodge structure is the same as Deligne's? In other words, I would like to understand what it is about the Hodge and weight filtrations on $\mathbb Q_X^H[n]$ which force the indices of the Hodge numbers of each $\mathrm{gr}^W_mH^k(X,\mathbb Q)$ to be positive (there are no $h^{p,q}$'s with $pq<0$). I am mostly interested in the projective case, but understanding the case for $X$ nonprojective would be nice too.
In the case that $X$ is smooth then this is easy because the constant Hodge module is completely explicit. In particular, $\mathbb Q_X^H[n]$ is the de Rham complex of $X$ and the Hodge filtration is bounded between $0$ and $n.$ The spectral sequence of a filtered complex therefore answers my question in this case. However, when $X$ is singular I suddenly know very little about the filtrations on $\mathbb Q_X^H[n].$ Any help is appreciated. I am no expert so if my understanding is off somewhere then please let me know.
